# React Native "Styled-components" not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am fairly new to react-native and javascript, I recently attemped to use styled components in react native, which allows you to style components using css-like syntax. In this case, I want to change the name of a **View** to **div** and then style it, but **div** is not being used and therefore the styles does not apply.

Here is my code:

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const div = styled.View` // "div" is not being used
  flex: 1; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  background-color: pink; 
`

function ScreenTimePage() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Text> Some Text </Text>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React requires that component names start with a capital letter so it can distinguish them from HTML elements.

Call it `Div` instead (better yet, name it something that describes what it is for and can’t be confused with an HTML element).